# Audio keeps playing when exoplayer releases

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using ExoPlayer in my dialog. I want the video to play automatically when dialog opens. When `simpleExoPlayer.prepare()` snippet is active I am able to do autoplay but when I close the dialog audio keeps playing. Before activating `simpleExoPlayer.prepare()` audio stops when I dismiss dialog. Is there another method to autoplay ExoPlayer or stop the audio when dialog dismiss?

```kotlin
class VideoViewDialog (context: Context) : BaseDialog<LayoutDialogVideoViewBinding>(context) {
    private var videoUrl : String = ""
    private lateinit var simpleExoPlayer: ExoPlayer

    override fun populateUi() {
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        mBinding?.apply {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    private fun initializePlayer() {
        val mediaDataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)

        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(
            MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl))

        val mediaSourceFactory: MediaSource.Factory = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(mediaDataSourceFactory)

        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
            .build()

        simpleExoPlayer.addMediaSource(mediaSource)

        simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare()

        mBinding?.apply {
            playerView.player = simpleExoPlayer
            playerView.requestFocus()
        }
        simpleExoPlayer.play()
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        simpleExoPlayer.release()
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) initializePlayer()
    }

    public override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) releasePlayer()
    }

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.layout_dialog_video_view
    }

    companion object{
        fun newInstance(
            context: Context,
            videoUrl : String,
        ) : VideoViewDialog {
            val dialog = VideoViewDialog(context)
            dialog.also {
                it.videoUrl = videoUrl
            }
            return dialog
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `.stop`, `clearVideoSurface()`, `playerView.player = null` before `.release()`. Didn't work it.

Comment: BaseDialog supports "onDismiss()" event to be overridden if the developer wants to do something when the Dialog is closed.

Comment: @emandt releasing exoplayer on onDismiss() also not working

Comment: Did you check if "onDismiss()" is executed in Runtime? Did you tried to call ".stop()" before ".release()"?

Comment: @emandt onDismiss() is executing. I tried ".stop", "clearVideoSurface()", "playerView.player = null" before ".release()".  Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you called `initializePlayer()` twice. resulting in two Exoplayer instances playing; you're only able to release the one the `simpleExoPlayer` variable holds a reference to.

Comment: I declared `simpleExoPlayer` as global lateinit var, and initialized in `initializePlayer()` function. This function runs under the `populateUi()` . Seems like `simpleExoPlayer` only initialized under `populateUi()` once.

Comment: seems like you also called it in onStart(), changing variable doesn't mean its destroyed. ExoPlayer keep itself alive with ApplicationContext so it will stay active until the app dies or the resource which include the context reference is released by calling release()